Solana Data on Validator Stake voted on a Block
Solana includes a lot of votes in each block and I wondered if there is some data around on how much % of the validator stake is actually voting on each block on average/histogram.
I found getblockcommitment but that is only kept for like 31 blocks or so.
Is there a good way to get this data for a longer timeframe? E.g. a year?

If you use getBlock, you can go back in time and fetch every single transaction ever executed on the chain. Unfortunately though, stake weight information isn't included in the on-chain transactions, so it'll be tough to calculate exactly how much stake voted on blocks. You can get the current information from getVoteAccounts and cross-reference that against the votes going forward though: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getvoteaccounts
